# Quarkus web app cannnot authorize with JWT and Keycloak

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, quarkus

I am trying to authorize a user using code grant flow in Keycloak to a Quarkus application.
Here is the Quarkus configuration

```
# OIDC Configuration
quarkus.oidc.auth-server-url=http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/quarkus
quarkus.oidc.client-id=web-application
quarkus.oidc.credentials.secret=ca21b304-XXX-XXX-XXX-51d38ef5da02
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
quarkus.oidc.authentication.scopes=email
```

The client configuration for "web-application" has only Standard Flow enabled (for Code Grant Flow)

[image: web app configuration]

- I access http://localhost:8080/
- I'm redirected to Keycloak (url looks good with `scope=openid+email&response_type=code&client_id=web-application`
- I log in with sample user account
- I'm redirected back with the code
- Then I get an exception in Quarkus

```
Caused by: org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 401 / Unauthorized / Response from server: {"error":"unauthorized_client","error_description":"Client not enabled to retrieve service account"}
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethod.execute(HttpMethod.java:95)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpMethodResponse$2.execute(HttpMethodResponse.java:50)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.TokenCallable.obtainAccessToken(TokenCallable.java:121)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.TokenCallable.call(TokenCallable.java:57)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.createFindRequest(ProtectedResource.java:276)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.access$300(ProtectedResource.java:38)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:205)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource$5.call(ProtectedResource.java:202)
    at org.keycloak.authorization.client.resource.ProtectedResource.find(ProtectedResource.java:210)
```

The error in Keycloak is:

```
09:58:25,420 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (default task-30) type=CLIENT_LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=quarkus, clientId=web-application, userId=null, ipAddress=172.17.0.1, error=invalid_client, grant_type=client_credentials, client_auth_method=client-secret
```

Question:
Why Quarkus tries to use "grant_type=client_credentials"? It should use the grant type = "authorization_code". This looks like a bug in Quarkus, but maybe there is a flag.

Answer (score 3):

"Service Account Enabled" is off. Enabling it should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try:

```
quarkus.oidc.client-type=web-app
```

instead of:

```
quarkus.oidc.application-type=web-app
```

Source: https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect-web-authentication

Comment: The property list at the bottom has only application-type. My sample works when I remove the keycloak dependecies.